# RewriteRule is not working when index.php is clicked

Tags: php, .htaccess

RewriteRule is not working when index.php is clicked. Below is my code :

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^home$ /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^bagsgentssel/([0-9]+)$ /bagsgentssel.php?h=$1 [L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /leather-product.php?n=$1 [QSA,L]
```

When index.php is loaded for the first time it perfects perfectly.

But when i clicks on other links such as : 
 Link1 : leather-product.php : on clicking this link, url changes to "localhost/leather-product/12" and 
Link2 : bagsfentssel.php : if i click on this link, url changes to "localhost/bagsgentssel/45"

After clicking above links, if i clicks on company logo which is basically a link to index.php, url then changes to "localhost/leather-product/index.php".

```
<a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" style="border:0px solid red;">
   <img src="/images/logo.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="xyz co">
</a>
```

Similarly if i click on Link2 url then changes to "localhost/leather-product/index.php"

Why this is happening. I know there must be something wrong in the code. But where? Please help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> <a href="index.php" class="navbar-brand" style="border:0px solid red;">
> ```

The problem here would seem to be that you are linking to a *relative* URL (`index.php`) in your HTML. For example, if the browser is currently viewing the URL `/leather-product/12` then a client-side *relative* URL such as `index.php` naturally resolves relative to `/leather-product/12` and becomes `/leather-product/index.php`. This all happens in the client-side HTML - in the browser.

Instead, you need to make the URL root-relative (slash prefix), ie. `/index.php`. (Or simply `/` - assuming your `DirectoryIndex` is set correctly.)

See also, this related question on the Webmasters stack:

- [.htaccess rewrite URL leads to missing CSS](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/86450/htaccess-rewrite-url-leads-to-missing-css)

---

> But when I click on other links such as : Link1 : leather-product.php : on clicking this link, url changes to "localhost/leather-product/12"

*Aside:* Just to clarify, the link itself shouldn't contain `leather-product.php` and the URL shouldn't be "changing" to `/leather-product/12` - as you seem to imply. The only visible link/URL you should see is `/leather-product/12`. `leather-product.php` should be entirely hidden from the client. (?)

Comment: yeah I understood, sorry that's my mistake. the link doesnot include ".php". First link is : "http://localhost/leather-product/12" and the second link is : "http://localhost/bagsgentssel/45".

Comment: Thank you very much sir. You really saved a lot of time. I am highly obliged.