# apache mod_rewrite path to querystring - keep base directory

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewrite

I try to "beautify" my URLs from eg. `www.example.com/page.php&id=3` to `www.example.com/page/3`

I can achieve this with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(page)/([0-9]+)$ page.php?id=$2
```

The problem is, that all my CSS files and scripts are referenced by relative paths, and therefore no longer found since the URL says `www.example.com/page/3` and now the base directory is `page` and no longer the DocumentRoot.

How can I achieve a rewrite and maintain the base directory so that the paths to the reference files are still valid.

Comment: This a problem with using relative URL-paths in your client-side code - not something you should solve with rewrites in `.htaccess`. It is the _browser_ that is is resolving these relative URL-paths, not the server.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RewriteRule is not working when index.php is clicked](https://serverfault.com/questions/952898/rewriterule-is-not-working-when-index-php-is-clicked)